# hyperref - pdflang attributes

Tags: hyperref

I try the following MWE (with LuaLatex 1.12.0 and hyperref v7.00d) and have two problems/questions:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} 

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={ABC – https...},
    pdftitle={title with German öäüß},
    pdflang={de}
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

1. In my PDF Viewers the language option is not displayed. I'm not sure if this is due to my PDFViewer or if this is not compiled into the PDF.
2. According to the documentation the `pdflang` should be RFC 3066. But looking for a list I didn't find one. When I follow the [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF16.html) from W3 I end up with [ISO 639-2 codes](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). Are they now same or different?

Comment: the language is there, with acrobat pro I also see it at the "reading options"("Leseoptionen" for me), adobe reader seems not to show it somewhere. `de` should be ok, or `de-DE`.

Comment: Aha... that's the difference - not much but somehow there ;-) Thx for the test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Let's say, we use the new (post-1996) German rules in Germany. Do we say `de` or `de-DE`? Or `deu`, `DEU`, `ger`, `de-DE-1996` or something else ? I found http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html and https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search and https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-3166-1-Kodierliste ; altogether they confuse me.